# Excel VBA - Simple Average Computation

Tags: excel, vba

Seems so simple, but I am not getting the expected result.

My attempt, simplified for illustration:

```
Sub myMacro2()

Dim intLastRow As Long
Dim intLastCol As Long
Dim numAve As Double
Dim i As Integer

intLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
intLastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To intLastRow Step 1
    numAve = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, intLastCol))
    MsgBox "Row: " & i & " Ave: " & numAve
Next i

End Sub
```

My data for this example (5 columns, populated from left to right), empty cells treated as NULL.

```
A   111         
B   111         
C   111 222 333 444
D   111 222     
E   111 222 333 
F   111 222
```

The msgBox returns "111" as the average value for each row.

I am pretty sure I am missing something fundamental or obvious, but it is eluding me.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: If you're trying to average the range, then it needs to be `.Average(.Range(.Cells(I, 2), .Cells(I, intLastCol)))`. That's assuming your range is correct. Note also the qualified range and cell objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not defining the range correctly.

> ```
> Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, intLastCol))
> ```

should be:

```
 Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, intLastCol)))
 '                                    ^^^^^^^
```

Without that, you are just averaging two cells, not the range *joining* the two cells.

Comment: A.S.H. - Thanks, I munged that construction in my example.  Ugh!

Comment: @MarkPelletier glad to help. By the way, in my tests on your data your code gets `277.5` on row 3. Think of changing the way you define your lastRow and lastCol: the `UsedRange` is unreliable and gives head-aches on the long run.